# want to highlight a route in a map for the city navigation application

Tags: java-me

i am preparing a city-map navigation mobile application in which i want to highlight a route to the user when he enters the two place's name. now, my problem is that i can find the places, but i am stuck at the part where i want to highlight the route between those two places.

can you please suggest some idea, so that i can use that in my application. thnQ

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a pathfinding algorithm to determine the path. If you want an efficient and pretty standard algorithm, there is an algorithm called A* for finding the best path between two places. It's a subject by itself.

Here is a nice tutorial to understand the algorithm:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)

And you can also google "a star pathfinding", and you'll find a lot on the subject.